# Differentiate 2 methods/uris with same uri parameters

Tags: wcf

I have 2 methods with same uri params as below, what is the best way of differentiating it based on the standard. (Currently im getting an error message as 'Each operation requires a unique combination of UriTemplate and Method to unambiguously dispatch messages')

uri 1: 
Params:**"/PortalId/{PortalId}/ProjectId/{ProjectId}"** ; 
Calling Method:**GetProjectInfo**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle= MessageBodyStyle.Bare,UriTemplate
="/PortalId/{PortalId}/ProjectId/{ProjectId}", 
ResponseFormat =     WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<SurveyProjects> GetProjectInfo(String PortalId, String ProjectId);
```

uri 2:
Params:**"/PortalId/{PortalId}/ProjectId/{ProjectId}"** ; 
Calling Method:**GetQuestionsByProjectId**

```
[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate 
="/PortalId/{PortalId}/ProjectId/{ProjectId}", 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        QuestionContainer GetQuestionsByProjectId(String PortalId, String ProjectId);
```

Comment: That's not a great URL structure, you'd be better off to have `/PortalId/{PortalId}/ProjectId/{ProjectID}/Info` and `/PortalId/{PortalId}/ProjectId/{ProjectID}/Questions`. Although I don't see why it's even necessary to have the variable names in the Url. It would be better as `/{PortalId}/{ProjectId}/Info`

Comment: also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342835/rest-url-naming-convention-items-id-vs-itemsid-id)

Comment: Thanks James, will go for mentioned format